# jquery show/hide div with css transition - Mobile responsive

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, hide, show

I'm trying to make a very lite weight (codewise) responsive menu. i have made this so far but i'm starting to think letting jquery do the transnational effect on the drop down is a bad idea as it doesn't look good on a mobile phone becuase of the frame rate i'm guessing? demo below

demo with code: http://jsfiddle.net/pv7cx8cg/

How can i do the same thing with Js and Css transistions? and is it a good idea to do it that way? Any help will be great, thanks.

Jquery:

```
    $( ".menu-icon" ).click(function() {
    $( ".navbar" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
    });
```

Html:

```
 <div id="header-bar">
 <button class="menu-icon">Menu</button>
 </div>

    <div class="navbar">
        <ul class="reponsive-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="home">Home</a></li>       
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="">Deals</a></li>  
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="">My Survivalist</a></li> 
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="">About</a></li>  
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="">Contact</a></li>    
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p>Content Moves with drop down</p>
```

Css:

```
#header-bar{
   min-width:200px;
   max-width:100%;
   height:50px;
   background:#29333A;
   display: block;
}

.navbar{
  display:none;
  background:#DDD;

}

ul.reponsive-nav li.nav-item{
   list-style-type:none;
   display:inline;
   float:left;
   margin:0;
   background:#FFF;
   width:100%;  /* Remove this and*/
   border-bottom:1px solid #DDD;/*this for desktop menu */
}

ul.reponsive-nav li.nav-item a{
  display: block;
  color:#333;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:16px;
  padding:9px 15px 6px 15px;
  padding:auto;
  text-decoration:none;
 }

p{
    display: inline-block;
    background:#0CB264;
    width:100%; 
    text-align:center;    
    padding:30px 0;
    margin-top:15px;
 }
```

Comment: did you test this on mobile devices ? I guess this works pretty good ..alternative you could transform from height: 0px to height:auto;

Comment: You can't have a css transition to height: auto; You'll need to transition to set the max-height and then transition the height to something bigger